# Monotouch Example for QuickLook PDF

Tags: pdf, xamarin.ios, quicklook

I am looking for a bare-bones pdf viewer example using the QuickLook Monotouch API.  I have searched and have found bits and pieces but just can't seem to get it all integrated.

I will be reading the pdf from a file pre-saved to the Personal folder on the iPad and would like to show the pdf as a modal view.

If someone could post a bare-bones example, that would be much appreciated.

What I have so far is below.

Thanks!

```
        path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        pdfPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "pdfReport.pdf");

        QLPreviewController myPdfController = new QLPreviewController();
        MyPdf pdfToShow = new MyPdf("", new Uri(""));   // Not sure about this line
        myPdfController.DataSource = pdfPath;           // Not sure what this line should be
        PresentModalViewController(myPdfController, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used a UIWebView and loaded it like this:

```
NSUrl docUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(PDFInvoice.FullFilename);
NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(docUrl);

webView.LoadRequest(request);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Even though it's not technically the answer to the question, I marked it as the answer since it got me where I needed to be.